# Why does my PolyLine keep drawing from origin (0,0)?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, polyline

I'm creating a [RandomWalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) program. Most of the program is working as it should, however, there is one major issue.

When the PolyLine is being drawn, it keeps being forced back to the origin (0,0) instead of where the last point was. I've been trying to see what I'm missing/doing wrong, but I can't locate the issue.

Any help would be appreciated; if more info is needed, just ask. Thanks.

**Main Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RandomWalk {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // Creating main frame
        JFrame main = new JFrame("RandomWalk - Version 1.0");
        main.setSize(800, 800);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setResizable(false);
        main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Creating content/container panel
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        main.setContentPane(container);

        // Creating scene/canvas
        Draw canvas = new Draw();
        canvas.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        container.add(canvas);

        main.toFront();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Drawing Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Draw extends JPanel {

    // Starting value for i
    public static int i = 1;

    // Increment for line length
    public static int inc = 10;

    // Choose amount of lines/moves
    public static int a = 10000;

    // Arrays for polyline points
    public static int[] xPoints = new int[a];
    public static int[] yPoints = new int[a];

    public Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            xPoints[0] = 400;
            yPoints[0] = 400;

            if (i < a) {

                double r = Math.random();

                if (r < 0.25) {
                    xPoints[i] = xPoints[i - 1] - inc;
                    yPoints[i] = yPoints[i - 1] - 0;
                    i++;
                } else if (r < 0.50) {
                    xPoints[i] = xPoints[i - 1] + inc;
                    yPoints[i] = yPoints[i - 1] + 0;
                    i++;
                } else if (r < 0.75) {
                    yPoints[i] = yPoints[i - 1] - inc;
                    xPoints[i] = xPoints[i - 1] - 0;
                    i++;
                } else if (r < 1.00) {
                    yPoints[i] = yPoints[i - 1] + inc;
                    xPoints[i] = xPoints[i - 1] + 0;
                    i++;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        timer.start();

        g.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that does work but it doesn't do quite what I want. I want to see the line being drawn every time. So every move it draws it. That's why I have it in a timer.

Comment: Oh wow. I definitely jumped the gun, sorry. Retracted close vote. :)

Comment: Might you want to use `g.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, i)` rather than `...(..., ..., xPoints.length)`?

Comment: Wow. That worked. Would you mind explaining it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `g.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, i);` rather than `g.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);`.

This is because if you use `xPoints.length`, you are telling it to use your entire `xPoints` and `yPoints` arrays, even when you haven't initialized `xPoints[j]` and `yPoints[j]` for all `j > i` (and so they are both `0`). If you use `i` as the length, it will only read those arrays up to index `i`, and all is good.